# Can WireMock conditionally change authorization header for integration test?

Tags: c#, integration-testing, wiremock, minimal-apis

I'm doing (learning about) integration testing on my web api.  One of my web api methods calls out to EXTERNAL web service that takes `Basic` authorization.

So, I've intercepted my external web api call via WireMock with the following code in my `WebApplicationFactory<>` class:

```
services.AddHttpClient( 
    $"ExternalApiClient", 
    httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri( wireMockServer.Url );
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue( 
                "Basic", 
                Convert.ToBase64String( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "secret" ) ) 
            );
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Accept", "*/*" );
    } 
);
```

With this, when I test my endpoint which requests its own `HttpClient` for the external service, it uses the WireMock server and serves up 'known' requests:

```
using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient( "ExternalApiClient" );
```

So I would like to write **two** tests:

1. Valid test where everything works.
2. Invalid test where my `Basic` authentication password is wrong.

I can't think of a clean way to do this.  Is there a WireMock (or integration test strategy) that would allow for this?  I've written a WireMock pattern matcher to successfully do this, but I have to manually run one test or the other based on whether I've put the right password in my `AddHttpClient` call (I can't run all tests within the project with my solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was as follows (if better options, please let me know):

Since the credential 'management' is inside the API that WireMock is replacing, I didn't really see a way to simulate a 'real scenario' where simply the credentials were wrong.  But all I really want to test is that *my* Api handles this error gracefully and returns expected result (a `Api-Authorization-Failed` header in the response).

So I just introduced a fake url that WireMock would intercept and return 'invalid credential response' but in reality, the callers of my web api would never pass this url.

```
server.Given(
    Request.Create()
        .WithPath( "/integration/unauthorized_api" )
        .UsingGet()
).RespondWith(
    Response.Create()
        .WithBody( @"{
        ""timestamp"": 1676572342225,
        ""status"": 401,
        ""error"": ""Unauthorized"",
        ""path"": ""{{request.path}}""
    }" )
        .WithHeader( "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8" )
        .WithStatusCode( HttpStatusCode.OK )
);
```

Then my `[Fact]` looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Get_ReturnsUnauthorized_WhenNexgenApiCredentialsAreWrong()
{
    // Arrange
    var payload = GetValidRequest( "/integration/unauthorized_api", null );
    
    // Act
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync( "/nexgen", payload );

    // Assert 
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be( HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized );
    response.Headers.Single( h => h.Key == "Api-Authorization-Failed" ).Value.First().Should().Be( "true" );
}
```